# How to add css in mail template in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: salesforce, email-templates, salesforce-service-cloud

I want created a mail template using salesforce marketing cloud. 
I have created a mail template in saleforce marketing cloud using blank template layout. 
I have added 10 'free form' as 10 sections. And added html into sections. 
I have also added some css using  tag in first section for styling.
When I test it by sending on test mail. It's work on other mail like :
kapil.bansal@csgroupchd.com, mail open in 'Thunderbird Mail'.
But css not working in g-mail(phptesting46@gmail.com). When I search for it,
I finded the reason for it. gmail not supported style tag in body tag.   https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
Now I am trying to added style in head tag. But I could not find any correct way. I am first time using this plateform. Please help me and suggest some solution for this.

Comment: Use style in the head and inline. You can use media queries on roughly 95% of email clients now. As @Tiaan pointed out Gmail only reads the first style tag and removes/strips any other ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Commonly stripped elements include JavaScript, object and embed tags,
>   and Flash. Gmail goes one step further and strips out both the head
>   and body tags, as well as any style tags in an email.

The best way to style elements in the body without a style tag or style sheet is inline styling:

```
<div style="background-color:#000000;"></div>
```

> The quickest way to insure your email campaign renders properly in Gmail is to place your most important styles inline.

Comment: Sorry to say but Gmail started supporting media query on both desktop and mobile since September 2016.